# Dart Pub Uploader section login format

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have published a package on http://pub.dartlang.org/ at first time and I see that my *full email* was published in the **Uploader** section at the right bottom of the page.

So, I don't really understand what is the format of my and other people's authorized login that is shown there? And how to remove/update my uploader's email?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?
How to avoid having the email address exposed?
If your email address is shown the format you used is probably correct.
You can compare it with other packages.
Many packages provide a link to GitHub where you can look at the pubspec.yaml.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah, exactly! I use some other format for the *Author* section and don't want to share my G's technical email.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer for example [here](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/color) I see only a login without a domain in that section.

Comment: extended my answer, maybe this is what you want to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you referenced in your comment uses this format:

`author: Name <user@domain.com>`

If you want to change your uploader information you can do this

> cd package_directory
>   pub uploader add newuser@mydomain.com
>   pub uploader remove olduser@somedomain.com

To authenticate with another account just delete
`~/.pub-cache/credentials.json`

Comment: But, as I said, that email is really different and *Uploader* section differ from *Author* section...

Comment: Different from what. Can you please add to your question how it currently is and how you want it to be?

Comment: I added an image to the question.

Comment: Yeah, that really worked! Thank you! As I understand now, the first publish action takes my primary email and adds it as a published regardless of *Authors*' section one.

Comment: Hmmm, it's very funny! After all the steps I cannot authorize as an owner of the package! It's all about the reported email from Google. The email is an old one but I've deleted the uploader with that reported login and set it to a new one which is not being reported under the current Google user... Going to try to change my primary email on Google Services...

Comment: Can't help here. I hadn't such a problem myself yet. If you don't get it working post your problem on the Dart Google group.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the good advice, but I managed it by adding a new user to my custom Google domain with that mail alias as a primary email. So deleted the auth cache and logged in again as a new custom user.